# How do I put Detailed Scenes in Blender

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation, mesh, particles

I'm Miguel Marquez and I have a question well I have a scene that I want to render with realistic hair particles. apparently, my goal is to have detailed scenes in films inside of Blender but whenever I do it ends up eats all my storage memory or crashes my mac mini so is there any tips and tricks I could use to get around those problems but still keep the detailed scenes? [image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is: You need to separate each character into a render layer. And use MASK and EXCLUSION. That´s for an advanced setup. It´s the only way your machine can render 1 character at the time. Later on the compositor, you can place them all back as renders on the same frame.
Otherwise: yes, your machine will keep crashing because of short RAM memory.

Thank you for your consideration to vote me as the answer by clicking to the left :the icon with a check mark and upvote this answer.

BFCT_Schiller